# Claim about holomorphic extension

Tags: complex-analysis, continuity, holomorphic-functions

> Prove or disprove the following claim.
>
> "For all continuous $f : S(0, 1) \to R$, there is a holomorphic $g : B(0, 1) \to C$ which extends to a continuous ${h : \overline {B(0, 1)}} \to C$ such that $\operatorname{Re}(h(z)) = f (z)$ for all $z \in S(0, 1)$?"

$S(0,1)$ is sphere of radius $1$ about the origin, and $B(0,1)$ is open ball of radius $1$ about the origin.$ \overline {B(0, 1)}$ is the closed ball of radius one about the origin.

Based on my attempts, this assertion appears to be true, but I am uncertain. Any assistance will be greatly appreciated. I initially tried to use contradiction to show that it was false, but all of my counterexamples had shortcomings.

Comment: How can $h$ be an extension of $g$ if they both have same domain??

Comment: My apologies. I made a notational error that I will fix. Thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this claim indeed is true. This is due to the fact that the Dirichlet Problem on the disk is solvable. See here for all the necessary details - http://people.reed.edu/~jerry/311/dirichlet.pdf